# How to map error response restkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm using RestKit v0.24.1

This is my response body for my request failure:

```
response.body={"status":400,"code":2007,"message":"Account password minimum length not satisfied.","developerMessage":"Account password minimum length not satisfied.","moreInfo":"http://docs.stormpath.com/errors/2007"}

2015-04-08 12:15:46.405 [20034:540848] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:407 Executing mapping operation for representation: {
    code = 2007;
    developerMessage = "Account password minimum length not satisfied.";
    message = "Account password minimum length not satisfied.";
    moreInfo = "http://docs.stormpath.com/errors/2007";
    status = 400;
}
```

This is my request:

```
RKObjectManager.sharedManager().postObject(account, path:STORMPATH_URL_ACCOUNTS, parameters: nil, success: {(operation: RKObjectRequestOperation!, result) in
            NSLog("New account created")
            onSuccess?()
            }, failure: {(operation: RKObjectRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in

                NSLog("New account NOT created")
                var userInfo = error.userInfo! as NSDictionary
                var errors = userInfo.objectForKey(RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey) as NSArray
                var lError = errors.lastObject as LError
                println("Message: \(lError.message)")
            }
        )
```

This is my "error" class that I want to map:

```
import Foundation
@objc(LError)
class LError: NSObject
{
    var status: NSNumber!
    var code: NSNumber!
    var message: String!
    var developerMessage: String!
}
```

Here is my descriptor code:

```
//Error mapping
        var errorMapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass: LError.self)
        errorMapping.addPropertyMapping(RKAttributeMapping(fromKeyPath: "status", toKeyPath: "status"))
        errorMapping.addPropertyMapping(RKAttributeMapping(fromKeyPath: "code", toKeyPath: "code"))
        errorMapping.addPropertyMapping(RKAttributeMapping(fromKeyPath: "message", toKeyPath: "message"))
        errorMapping.addPropertyMapping(RKAttributeMapping(fromKeyPath: "developerMessage", toKeyPath: "developerMessage"))
        var errorDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: errorMapping, pathPattern: nil, keyPath: nil, statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClass.ClientError))
        responseDescriptors.addObject(errorDescriptor)
```

And here is the problem RestKit yells at me about when trying to map the response:

```
(400 Bad Request / 0 objects) [request=0.5180s mapping=0.0000s total=0.5246s]:
error=Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched." UserInfo=0x7a8329b0 {DetailedErrors=(
), NSLocalizedFailureReason=The mapping operation was unable to find any nested object representations at the key paths searched: 
The representation inputted to the mapper was found to contain nested object representations at the following key paths: code, developerMessage, message, moreInfo, status
This likely indicates that you have misconfigured the key paths for your mappings., NSLocalizedDescription=No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched., keyPath=null}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're adding `responseDescriptors` to the object manager?

Comment: Yes. ```objectManager.addResponseDescriptorsFromArray(responseDescriptors)```

Comment: The code looks ok. Client error should cover all 4XX response codes. Key path nil should be the same as empty string and match everything. Turn on trace logging and see what additional details it gives about the key paths searched.